# PyMysql update data

Tags: mysql, python-3.4, pymysql

When I use MySQL Workbench I could know the result of updating data like this

[image]

When I use PyMySQL like this:

```
connect = pymysql.Connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='*', passwd='*', db='MySQL', charset='utf8')
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('update table_name set id=0 where id=1')
connect.commit()
connect.close()
```

How can I know the result?

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of affected rows by a DML query (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`) you should inspect [`cursor.rowcount`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount). To get number of matched rows you can run a `SELECT` query before you `UPDATE` with the same `WHERE` clause.

```
import pymysql    

conn = pymysql.Connect(user='guest', db='test', autocommit=True)
conn.begin()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE test_id IN(1, 2, 3)')
print('matched', cursor.fetchone()[0])

cursor.execute('UPDATE test SET value=0 WHERE test_id IN(1, 2, 3)')
print('changed', cursor.rowcount)

conn.rollback()
```